# Java - URI is not hierarchical error appears only in the exported JAR, not in Eclipse

Tags: java, url, winapi, java-io

I have a Java program that is able to change the wallpaper taking in input an image using WINAPI.

Everything works fine when I run it inside Eclipse IDE, but when I run the JAR I got the error:

**Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: URI is not hierarchical**

```
public class Main {

//INIT USER32 for WINAPI
public static interface User32 extends Library {
    User32 INSTANCE = (User32) Native.loadLibrary("user32",User32.class,W32APIOptions.DEFAULT_OPTIONS);        
    boolean SystemParametersInfo (int one, int two, String s ,int three);         
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, URISyntaxException {

        //Change wallpaper
        System.out.println("Change wallpaper");
        URL url = Main.class.getResource("/resources/img.jpg");
        File f = new File(url.toURI());
        String path = f.getPath();
        User32.INSTANCE.SystemParametersInfo(0x0014, 0, path , 1);
    }
}
```

The image is shipped within the JAR, so maybe the error is related to this since the program is not able to correctly read to URL inside the JAR.
Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

A jar file is just a compressed file when the resource is bundled as a jar java will be treated as a single file, which means it will not access to your resources.

try using this instead `getResourceAsStream(...);`

Comment: I also tried getResourceAsStream, but the InputStream class has no way to represent the URI, but I need it to pass as parameter to the file constructor in order to pass it again to WINAPI. Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: in this case, you can always send it as a binary by using ByteArrayInputeStream, or don't embed the img inside the jar

Comment: @user840718 When packaged in a JAR file the resource is no longer an actual file on the file system, it's an entry in the JAR file. This is why it's _always wrong_ to use `File` when dealing with resources. Now, Java can handle URLs which have a `jar:` scheme (e.g. `jar:file:///path/to/jar/file.jar!/image.jpg`) due to the `JarURLConnection` API but I doubt the WinAPI knows how to access such a URL—unless JNA does something special (does it?). You may have to extract the resource into an external file and then pass the URL to _that_ file instead or not use a resource in the first place.